# FATAL error: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isEof' was called on null. Receiver: null on Dart and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Hi this error appears in Android Studio:

Anyone had this problem before, how to fix this i tried to reinstall Dart and Android Studio with no success.

Thanks!

And this is the report:

```
Dart analysis server, SDK version 2.7.2, server version 1.27.4, FATAL error: 
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isEof' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isEof
#0      Driver._captureExceptions.errorFunction (package:analysis_server/src/server/driver.dart:723:7)
#1      _CustomZone.handleUncaughtError (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:19)
#2      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:927:7)
#3      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
#4      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#5      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#6      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:393:30)
#7      _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)

1587778349634 => {"id":"7","method":"flutter.setSubscriptions","params":{"subscriptions":{"OUTLINE":["C:\Petrolog\Flutter\MikeChaRi\neibor\lib\main.dart","C:\Petrolog\Flutter\MikeChaRi\neibo
1587778349650 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[],"removedLibraries":[]}}
1587778349650 <= {"id":"1"}
1587778349661 <= {"id":"2"}
1587778349666 <= {"id":"3","result":{"templates":[{"name":"assert","key":".assert","example":"expr.assert -> assert(expr);"},{"name":"fori","key":".fori","example":"limit.fori -> for(var i = 0; i < li
1587778350314 <= {"event":"analysis.errors","params":{"file":"C:\Petrolog\Flutter\MikeChaRi\neibor\pubspec.yaml","errors":[]}}
1587778350319 <= {"event":"analysis.errors","params":{"file":"C:\Petrolog\Flutter\MikeChaRi\neibor\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml","errors":[]}}
1587778350321 <= {"event":"analysis.errors","params":{"file":"C:\Petrolog\Flutter\MikeChaRi\neibor\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml","errors":[]}}
1587778350326 <= {"event":"analysis.errors","params":{"file":"C:\Petrolog\Flutter\MikeChaRi\neibor\android\app\src\profile\AndroidManifest.xml","errors":[]}}
1587778350580 <= {"id":"4"}
1587778350583 <= {"id":"5"}
1587778350593 <= {"id":"6"}
1587778350597 <= {"id":"7"}
1587778350598 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[],"removedLibraries":[]}}
1587778352994 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":0,"uri":"package:neybor/widgets/text_message.dart","items":[{"label":"TextMessage","declaringLibraryUri"
1587778353004 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":1,"uri":"package:google_sign_in/widgets.dart","items":[{"label":"GoogleUserCircleAvatar","declaringLibra
1587778353022 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":2,"uri":"package:google_sign_in_platform_interface/google_sign_in_platform_interface.dart","items":[{"la
1587778353041 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":5,"uri":"package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart","items":[{"label":"GoogleUserCircleAvatar","declari
1587778353051 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":7,"uri":"package:quiver/core.dart","items":[{"label":"hashObjects","declaringLibraryUri":"package:quiver
1587778353061 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":10,"uri":"package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart","items":[{"lab
1587778353069 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":14,"uri":"package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart","items":[{"label":"FirebaseApp","declaringLibraryUri
1587778353076 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":16,"uri":"package:plugin_platform_interface/plugin_platform_interface.dart","items":[{"label":"MockPlatf
1587778353091 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":17,"uri":"package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/firebase_auth_platform_interface.dart","items":[{"lab
1587778353121 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":20,"uri":"package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart","items":[{"label":"IdTokenResult","declaringLibraryU
1587778353126 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":36,"uri":"package:neybor/models/firebase_login.dart","items":[{"label":"user","declaringLibraryUri":"pac
1587778353128 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":37,"uri":"package:neybor/screens/register_screen.dart","items":[{"label":"RegisterScreen","declaringLibr
1587778353137 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":38,"uri":"package:nested/nested.dart","items":[{"label":"Nested","declaringLibraryUri":"package:nested/n
1587778353175 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":39,"uri":"package:provider/provider.dart","items":[{"label":"Selector","declaringLibraryUri":"package:pr
1587778353181 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":50,"uri":"package:neybor/models/data.dart","items":[{"label":"Data","declaringLibraryUri":"package:neybo
1587778353286 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":65,"uri":"dart:nativewrappers","items":[]}],"removedLibraries":[]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem upon analysis discovered that somehow the flutter SDK files were corrupted. And I re-installed the SDKs and it resolved my issue.

Re installation - I had my flutter SDKs installed under C:\src\flutter. I deleted the entire flutter folder and ran downloaded the latest stable version from https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows and extracted the zip file to C:\src.